# Connect to NFCTagReaderSession NFCISO7816Tag tag and send command in iOS 13

Tags: ios, swift, nfc, ios13, core-nfc

I am working on NFCTagReaderSession the newly available in iOS 13, i struck to connect the session tag and send apdu commands for communication.

when i call the connect property it looks long time like 15 secs to connect by the time when it is connected(beeps sound) it shows an error message

> NFCError Code=201 "Session timeout".

Every time `tagReaderSession:didInvalidateWithError` is calling while connecting the card and i could not send apdu commands.

the code which i tried to connect and send apudu command

```
var nfcSession: NFCTagReaderSession?  
nfcSession = NFCTagReaderSession(pollingOption: [.iso14443],      delegate: self, queue: DispatchQueue.main)
nfcSession?.alertMessage = "Hold your iPhone near an NFC."
nfcSession?.begin()

// MARK: - NFCTagReaderSessionDelegate

public func tagReaderSessionDidBecomeActive(_ session: NFCTagReaderSession) {
    print("tagReaderSessionDidBecomeActive")
}

public func tagReaderSession(_ session: NFCTagReaderSession, didInvalidateWithError error: Error) {
    print( "tagReaderSession:didInvalidateWithError - \(error)" )
}

public func tagReaderSession(_ session: NFCTagReaderSession, didDetect tags: [NFCTag]) {

let tag = tags.first!
var nfcTag7816: NFCISO7816Tag
switch tags.first! {
 case let .iso7816(tag):
     nfcTag7816 = tag
   @unknown default :
        session.invalidate(errorMessage: "Tag not valid.")
             return
   }

 session.connect(to: tags.first!) { (error: Error?) in
     if error != nil {
        session.invalidate(errorMessage: "Connection error. Please try again.")
           return
    }
    else {
        let myAPDU = NFCISO7816APDU(instructionClass:0, instructionCode:0xB0, p1Parameter:0, p2Parameter:0, data: Data(), expectedResponseLength:16)
         nfcTag7816.sendCommand(apdu: myAPDU) { (response: Data, sw1: UInt8, sw2: UInt8, error: Error?)
                     in

        guard error != nil && !(sw1 == 0x90 && sw2 == 0) else {
               session.invalidate(errorMessage: "Applicationfailure")
            return
            }
          }
       }
   }
}
```

Error found when connected:

```
tagReaderSession:didInvalidateWithError - Error Domain=NFCError Code=201 "Session timeout" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Session timeout}
```

Please suggest me the exact reason of happening this one, and so that i can change in code according to the solutions

Comment: I am facing the same issue. After connecting to 7816Tag, I start sending APDU commands to card. But after 20 seconds NFCTagReaderSession is getting invalidated. If you just start NFCTagReaderSession and do not tap card, then it will wait for 60 seconds and invalidate. I am looking for solution for this.

Comment: any one please provide solutions  this.......

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58191748/nfctagreadersession-has-timeout-of-20-seconds-how-to-increase-it

Comment: Did you find any solution for this yet ?