# NFCTagReaderSession has timeout of 20 seconds. How to increase it?

Tags: nfc, ios13, core-nfc

I am trying to send APDU commands to NFC card that contains ISO7816 Tag 
I will open session:

```
readerSession = NFCTagReaderSession(pollingOption: [.iso14443], delegate: self, queue: nil)
readerSession?.begin()
```

Once the tag is detected,

```
session.connect(to: tags.first!)
```

and start sending APDU commands one by one.

```
detectedTag.sendCommand(apdu: apduCommand) { (response: Data, sw1: UInt8, sw2: UInt8, error: Error?)
```

But after about 20 seconds NFCTagReaderSession is sending the error:

```
Error Domain=NFCError
Code=201 "Session timeout"
UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Session timeout}
```

Is there a possibility to increase the timeout of communication with connected tag?
I tried looking for interval or timeout property of NFCTagReaderSession. But no luck.

Comment: 201 Sounds like an Entitlements issue. Have you included the new key:value pair in your entitlements file?

Comment: Yes, I have included the new key:value pair for Tag reader session format

Comment: @Naren did you find any solutions for the same?

Comment: @SAMIRRATHOD No. Did not find anything on that. Did you get any solution. ?

Comment: @Naren nope.. didn't get solution