# Is it possible to have user interaction while using NFCISO7816Tag with CoreNFC on iOS 13?

Tags: ios, swift, core-nfc

I also posted my questions to [Apple developer forums](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/131917).

I'm working on an application to address NFCISO7816Tag with some success until now. Here are the limitations that I found and my questions:

1) After beginning the reader session, the NFC UIAlertMessage pops up in foreground. We can update the text with the alertMessage function. This UIAlertMessage exists until the session is invalidated. This behaviour prevents having interactions with the user while NFC communications are in place.

- Is this right ?
- Is there any way to allow user interaction while a reader session is started ? Let say to enter a PIN code for example or to click on a button in some UI ?

2) When starting to scan with a begin reader session, it seems that the scanning has a timeout of 60s ?

- Is this statement true ? It seems as of Naren comment in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58188447/connect-to-nfctagreadersession-nfciso7816tag-tag-and-send-command-in-ios-13).
- Is there any way to customise this timeout ?

3) When starting to communicate with a NFCISO7816Tag, it seems that the communication windows is bound to 20s ?

- Is this statement true ? It seems as of Naren comment in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58188447/connect-to-nfctagreadersession-nfciso7816tag-tag-and-send-command-in-ios-13).
- Is there any way to customise/increase this timeout ?

If of any interest, I'm currently using Xcode 11.4.1, iPhone Xr iOS 13.4.1 and swift.

Regards,

++dom

Comment: Welcome to SO. It's recommended that you have only one question per topic - see also [ask].

Comment: AFAIK the answers are:

1) Yes. No.
2) Yes. No.
3) Yes. No.

Comment: Thank you for the confirmation Gereon. koen, I will do it next time. I thought that this 3 items could be asked in the same question as they are related to the same topic.